# Discord bot is reading old prefix also

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I changed prefix from + to = and now it is taking old prefix also I can't find any soln for it I made the new application but it is still the same. I tried console.log it shows new prefix

````js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix= '=';


const guildID = '';
const token = '';
var ques;





//Ready Event
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Officer is ready for the Patrol!')
    
});


//bot status

//Message Event
client.on('message', async message => {
  //args
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  //commands
  if (command === 'report') {
    //Has to be in DMs
    if (message.channel.type != 'dm') {
        message.delete();
        
      
    

       let appChannel = (await message.author.send("```Please fill all the details if you don't want to continue then type cancel```")).channel
       
      
      

      //First Question
      while(1){
        await message.author.send('**Have you read all the prerequisites for the reporting system? (yes/no)**');
      let answer = await appChannel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id, {
        max: 1
      });
      const tf = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join()).toLowerCase();
      if(tf==='cancel'){
        message.author.send("***Request has been cancelled***");
        return;
      }
      if(tf==='no'){
        message.author.send("**Please read all the prerequisites for the reporting system in #report-here**");
        return;
      }

      //Second Question
      await message.author.send('**Send message link for the message to be reported**');
      answer = await appChannel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id, {
        max: 1
      });
      const msg1 = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join());
        if(msg1==='cancel'||msg1==='Cancel'||msg1==='CANCEL'){
        message.author.send("***Request has been cancelled***");
        return;
      }

      //Third Question
      await message.author.send('**Provide some further information**');
      answer = await appChannel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id, {
        max: 1
      });
      const msg2 = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join());
        if(msg2==='cancel'||msg2==='Cancel'||msg2==='CANCEL'){
        message.author.send("***Request has been cancelled***");
        return;
      }
        
      message.author.send("```Your request has been submitted. Expect message from Mods in case there is extra message required```");
        
  
        

      //Embed
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .addField('Accused Message Link', msg1)
        .addField('Info', msg2)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor("#0000FF")
        .addField('userID', message.author.id);

      //Sending Embed
      const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID);
      await guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '712146301340352632').send(embed);
        
        return;
      }
      

    }

  }
  if(command==='trivia'){
    if(message.type != 'dm'){
      message.delete();
      
        let appChannel = (await message.author.send("```Answer the follwing questions```")).channel
        while(1){
        await message.author.send('**Are sure you have the correct answer you weeb?**');
        let answer = await appChannel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id, {
        max: 1
      });
        const weeb = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join()).toLowerCase();
        if(weeb==='no'){
          message.author.send("*** I guess you wasn't that big of a weeb. Come again when you have the answer***");
        return;
        }
        await message.author.send(ques);
        answer = await appChannel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id, {
        max: 1
      });
        const ans = (answer.map(answers=>answers.content).join());
        message.author.send("You answer has been submitted. Good Luck");
        
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .addField('Question:', ques)
        .addField('Trivia Answer', ans)
        .setTimestamp()
        .addField('userID', message.author.id);
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID);
        await guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '712146046389846016').send(embed);
        
        return;
      }
      
      
      
    }
    
  }
  
  if(command === 'ads'){
    if(message.type != 'dm'){
      message.delete();
      let appChannel = (await message.author.send("Fill all the details properly")).channel
      while(1){
        await message.author.send("Before we start read #faq. If you already have then reply anything or else type cancel");
        let answer = await appChannel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id,{max: 1});
        const ans = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join()).toLowerCase();
        if(ans === 'cancel'){
          message.author.send("```Request Has Been Cancelled ```");
          return;
        }
        await message.author.send("Send the episode URL");
        answer = await appChannel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id,{max: 1});
        const epi = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join())
        
        await message.author.send("Send the ad URL");
        answer = await appChannel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id,{max: 1});
        const ad = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join())

        await message.author.send("what problem did you experience with this ad?");
        answer = await appChannel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id,{max: 1});
        const admore = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join())
        
        await message.author.send("Are you sure you want to submit it? (yes/no)");
        answer = await appChannel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id,{max: 1});
        const sure = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join()).toLowerCase();
        if(sure === 'yes'){
          message.author.send("Request has been submitted");
          const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
          .addField('Episode:', epi)
          .addField('Ad:', ad)
          .addField('info:', admore)
          .setTimestamp()
          .addField('userID', message.author.id);
          const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID);
          await guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '628016171337252875').send(embed);
          return;
        }
        else{
          message.author.send("Request has been Cancelled");
          return;
        }
       
        
      }
    }
}
  


if(command === 'question'){
    if(message.type != 'dm'){
        if(message.author.id === '687893451534106669'|| message.author.id==='378583063178772491' || message.author.id === '303540460264226820'){
            await message.channel.send("Type the new question");
            let answer = await message.channel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id,{max: 1});
            ques = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join())
            message.channel.send("Question has been set for trivia")
        }
        else{
            message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use it")
        }
    }
}



if(command === 'help'){
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .addField('Commands', 'report , ads , trivia')
          .addField('Fun', 'admin, mod')
          .setTimestamp();
          
          message.channel.send(embed);
}


  
client.user.setPresence({activity: {type: 'WATCHING', name: "move"}, status: 'online'}).then(console.log).catch(console.error);


});


//Log In
client.login(token);
````

I have changed the whole application but it is still the same. I changed the variable name no effect tried it on different node server still same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not actually checking if the prefix is written but only remove the first `prefix.length` char(s) to get the command name.

If you try `$report` your `report` command will trigger too.

I suggest you to wrap your command name checking if statements in an if statement checking if the message starts with your prefix like so :

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    //args
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        //commands
        if (command === 'report') {
            ...
        }

        ...
    }
}
```